# SQLiteexception database disk image is malformed

Tags: sql, sqlite, diskimage

I have a weird error with a SQLite Database: [You can download it here](https://ufile.io/c5tq6)

Everytime I try to insert something in the Table "CurrencyTransactions" it fails because a new column called `7` appeared for no reason.

[image: weird 7 column]

I tried to drop the table but

[image: drop table fail]

I ran `PRAGMA integrity_check` but I've this error then

[image: pragma integrity fail]

Then I tried to export a `.sql` file and to import it again in a fresh new database but

**1)** If I import the structure only, it works fine and I don't have the `7` column anymore

**2)** If I import the entries then, it fails with this error:
*It means something like: "Error in process #74: not an error"*

[image: import entries fail]

To finish, I also tried [this solution](https://techblog.dorogin.com/sqliteexception-database-disk-image-is-malformed-77e59d547c50) but the new database created is empty.

**What can I do?** I really need to save the entries.

Comment: You must restore from the backup.

Comment: I don't have any backup

Answer (score 4):

What I suggest is in DB Browser.

1. File/Export/Database to SQL file.
2. Select All (for all tables)
3. Other options up to you other than Export Everything
4. Save the file.
5. Close the database.
6. Open a new database e.g nadekobotfix.db. (could be same name but different location)

   - Note 1-6 takes a minute or so (just under 60k).
7. Do the hard work according to :-

You may need to remove/ignore the first and last lines (`BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and the subsequent `COMMIT;`)

You would probably not be able to run the generated SQL directly due to constraints (tried this an failed with constraints).

You need to copy sections from the file and run according to the hierarchy as imposed by the constraints (foreign keys). If you have CHECK constraints these may need to be considered. (no Triggers to worry about).

- Running `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND instr(sql,'CHECK');` returns nothing so there are no **CHECK** constraints.

Indexes could/should be left till last (as they are in the generated SQL).

A section would consist of a table's create statement along with the insert statements.

You may wish to create a spreadsheet of the tables(sections) marking them off when they have been done.

- The following query could assist as those with NA could be done first

  - `SELECT CASE WHEN instr(sql,'FOREIGN KEY') THEN 'FK' ELSE 'NA' END AS fkey, name,sql 
    FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite%'  ORDER BY instr(sql,'FOREIGN KEY')`
- you could export individual tables from DB Browser for SQlite marking them off when done.

You may wish to do an **`integrity_check`** at regular intervals.

If this works (you might have to make adjustments to the SQL) then you can rename the old db and then rename the new (or move the old and the copy the new if using the same database name).

- **Note** you may still have to determine how the corruption occurred.
- You may wish to backup the database regularly.
- You may wish to have a look at [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)

You may wish to heed :-

> With few exceptions, analysis of a corrupt database does not normally 
>   help to determine what went wrong.  A better approach to avoiding 
>   "danger", we have found, is to read and understand 
>   https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html
>
> > *** in database main *** 
> >     Page 10628: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
>
> This indicates that the page header is so badly corrupted that SQLite 
>   cannot interpret this page at all.  One possible reason:  page 10628 
>   has been zeroed.  Can you look at a hex dump of that page?  (Remember 
>   that SQLite numbers pages beginning with 1, so the start of the page 
>   is pgsz*10627 where pgsz is the page size.) 
>   --  D. Richard Hipp

[“btreeInitPage() returns error code 11”](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/btreeInitPage-returns-error-code-11-td87095.html)

### Sample adjustment required

The **Reminders** table has a column called When, this is an SQL keyword (inadvisable column name IMO) so the generated SQL for the INSERT doesn't wrap the column name so you will get an error.

i.e. :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reminders` (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `ChannelId` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `IsPrivate` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Message`   TEXT,
    `ServerId`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `UserId`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `When`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `DateAdded` TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `Reminders` (Id,ChannelId,IsPrivate,Message,ServerId,UserId,When,DateAdded) VALUES (1270,367886754973351936,1,'Birthday Day',318127386367623170,367886754973351936,'2018-05-03 22:07:48.1860996','2018-03-18 22:07:48.186101'),
 (1271,248278722656993281,1,'to remind Chanmi to remind Jayos to DeagleMomoka',318127386367623170,248278722656993281,'2018-05-05 22:08:58.4915565','2018-03-18 22:08:58.4915582'),
 (1376,170240129414201344,1,'timely',318127386367623170,170240129414201344,'2018-03-29 09:00:29.4476776','2018-03-28 09:00:29.447679'),
 (1377,373301201158144000,1,'timely',318127386367623170,373301201158144000,'2018-03-29 09:50:14.1631563','2018-03-28 09:50:14.1631577'),
 (1378,248278722656993281,1,'timely',318127386367623170,248278722656993281,'2018-03-29 11:24:27.0250275','2018-03-28 11:24:27.025029'),
 (1379,421433212716318721,1,'to timely',318127386367623170,421433212716318721,'2018-03-29 19:21:17.7465563','2018-03-28 19:21:17.7465584'),
 (1380,346513954966863872,1,'t',318127386367623170,346513954966863872,'2018-03-29 19:42:23.4758798','2018-03-28 19:42:23.4758816'),
 (1381,272735316002209792,1,'t!daily',318127386367623170,272735316002209792,'2018-03-29 21:01:47.5616218','2018-03-28 21:01:47.5616236'),
 (1382,298272937243312132,1,'timely',318127386367623170,298272937243312132,'2018-03-29 23:18:02.8826873','2018-03-28 23:18:02.8826891'),
 (1383,332340162774302720,1,'t',318127386367623170,332340162774302720,'2018-03-30 01:55:21.4704139','2018-03-29 01:55:21.4704156'),
 (1384,367165474246754314,1,'tatyahaksodoeo',318127386367623170,367165474246754314,'2018-03-30 03:46:18.8805182','2018-03-29 03:46:18.8805196'),
 (1385,290086674761908225,1,'timely',318127386367623170,290086674761908225,'2018-03-30 07:02:33.4115303','2018-03-29 07:02:33.4115321'),
 (1386,168064128500367360,1,'timely',318127386367623170,168064128500367360,'2018-03-30 07:19:09.1915867','2018-03-29 07:19:09.1915885');
```

would have to be changed to use *(square brackets, single or double quotes or grave accents can be used to enclose/wrap/quote the offending keyword)*:-

```
.......INSERT INTO `Reminders` (Id,ChannelId,IsPrivate,Message,ServerId,UserId,[When],DateAdded) ......
```

- Likewise table  **SelfAssignableRoles** has the GROUP keyword as a column name.
- Likewise table **Permissionv2** and table **StartupCommand** have the INDEX keyword as a column name.

### Potential Issue

As an exercise I've tried doing the above and have managed to get 67 out of the 71 tables (66 out of 70 of your tables as *sqlite_sequence* is automatically created).

However, there appears to be an issue, between the **Clubs** table and the **DiscordUser** table. I believe that there is a circular reference between them. Thus as **WaifuInfo** and **WaifuUpdates**  are reliant upon the **DiscordUser** table and as **WaifuItem** is realiant upon **WaifInfo**. The tables mentioned here have not been successfully copied.

A word of warning. If you attempt to create **Clubs** and or **DiscordUser** using the existing constraints you may end up in a situation where one always has to exist.

e.g. if **DiscordUser** exists but **Clubs** doesn't then

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DiscordUser`;
```

results in :-

```
no such table: main.Clubs: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DiscordUser`;
```

If you then create **Clubs** and try the DROP with a very basic (no Constraints) using :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Clubs` (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DiscordUser`;
```

The result is good as per :-

```
Query executed successfully: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DiscordUser`; (took 1ms)
```

Now try to DROP **Clubs** using :-

```
--CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Clubs` (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DiscordUser`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Clubs`;
```

and you can't as **DiscordUser** doesn't exist as per :-

```
no such table: main.DiscordUser: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Clubs`;
```

- I've tried closing the database in case it was a caching issue but the behaviour remains.

As such, I'd strongly suggest having a good look at the constraint usage and being sure of correcting the issues before trying to copy all of the tables (I guess that there is a chance that this could be part of the cause of the corruption, however why/how is way beyond me).

P.S. The method I used was (1-6):-

Then for 7 :-

Run the sqlite_master query, from above, select all cells and copy, then drop the results into a spreadsheet (you could drop the sql column as the create gets truncated unless you try to fiddle with the delimiters).

1. Open the exported file (I used NotePad++) in your Editor.
2. Open a new DB in DB Browser (will refer to it as **DBB** from now) for SQLite.
3. In DBB in EXEC SQL tab, input `PRAGMA integrity_check`, run to check.
4. Create new tab (for next SQL).
5. Switch to Spreadsheet and copy the first table name that isn't marked as done.
6. Switch to Editor do find on EXISTS `copied_table_name`
7. Select the section (i.e the CREATE statement along to and including the last row to be inserted, note can be a pain for the larger tables so might be easier to create separate export for those tables). Copy the selection to the clipboard.
8. Paste into the empty tab and run.
9. If OK then

   - in DBB click to create a new tab for the next
   - switch to spreadsheet and mark table as DONE
   - goto 5.
10. If not OK then

    - If you can fix the issue by altering the SQL fix the SQL (e.g. column name needs enclosing/wrapping/quoting) and then go to 9.
    - If the issue is due to Constraints then go to 5 but select the table causing the constraint.

OK the issue with the DiscordUser/Club tables is that a Clubs.Ownerid requires a DiscordUser. So clubs cannot be added without the relevant Discord users (id's 1,2,7,14 and 32). Some DiscordUsers are club members so they require a club to exist.

What I have done is to load the DiscordUsers rows for the Club owners changing their ClubId to null. Load the Clubs. Update the ClubId's of the DiscordUsers so they are members of the club that they were before (i.e. undo the null) and to load the rest of the nearly 600 Discordusers (excluding those already loaded).

Here's the SQL I used for that part (note except for the Discorduser, Clubs and the 3 waifu tables, all other tables have been successfully created and loaded).

```
INSERT INTO `DiscordUser` (Id,AvatarId,Discriminator,UserId,DateAdded,Username,ClubId,LastLevelUp,NotifyOnLevelUp,LastXpGain,TotalXp,IsClubAdmin,CurrencyAmount) VALUES 
 -- ClubId was 6 changed to null
 (1,'6d5212a0f5e862d57c8ffc6f254a2e85','1458',299779864045682689,'2017-10-07 18:02:04.8287878','Anubis',NULL,'2018-03-27 02:22:26.362966',0,'2017-11-17 01:19:14.0313957',7056,1,280),
 -- Owns a club but not in a club
 (2,'3b37e0f635706f81fdde2b6de9889283','9810',181200115539640321,'2017-10-07 18:04:39.767728','AnnaHime',NULL,'2018-01-02 02:27:38.8011863',0,'2017-11-16 01:29:49.0371488',429,0,360),
 -- ClubId null was 3
 (7,'612c67b6eb57d8806dcc92ed45b3a6d0','0396',177502331582021639,'2017-10-07 18:11:09.7830603','Tsuchimursu',NULL,'2018-03-28 17:45:53.7399883',0,'2017-11-17 15:53:59.084885',18156,1,4725),
 -- ClubId null was 4
 (14,'b2dd362171277337294de325bf92ad6a','3267',215597863441268737,'2017-10-07 18:45:54.8092675','LaLaâ˜†Star',NULL,'2018-01-14 20:52:15.7531274',0,'2017-11-08 19:00:22.7778305',2061,1,286),
 -- ClubId null was 5
 (32,'667f4d802b977c4d4be974e35ae63c55','2593',251689019929395200,'2017-10-08 00:58:16.6089546','username',NULL,'2018-03-28 07:27:34.9348084',0,'2017-11-17 20:02:14.0283998',4704,1,1188),
 -- ClubId was 2 changed to NULL
 (91,'0adb399c9f2cd94370038e2452ab8c8d','6790',346513954966863872,'2017-10-13 05:48:51.7788964','mayoi',NULL,'2018-03-24 02:50:06.8970518',0,'2017-11-17 20:01:29.0692552',7635,1,515)
 ;

INSERT INTO `Clubs` (Id,DateAdded,Discrim,ImageUrl,MinimumLevelReq,Name,OwnerId,Xp,Description) VALUES 
 (2,'2017-11-14 07:39:57.5091592',1,'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_7WKFouxTx1fdFpnmmuykDAd5SoiiJOPzHdRmXKOmRRZhV5Ba4V_kZct5ooVjQ9BuzU=w300',5,'We â¤ waifus',91,40137,'Love your waifus short & tall, big & small, cute as dolls, we love ''em all!'),
 (3,'2017-12-11 07:00:59.3762914',1,'',30,'Den of Faes',7,11607,NULL),
 (4,'2017-12-11 07:03:59.093402',1,'',5,'Skeleton Enthusiasts',14,657,NULL),
 (5,'2017-12-11 07:05:56.9111719',1,'',5,'Saki''s Juice',32,2610,NULL),
 (6,'2017-12-22 04:46:24.7271709',1,'',5,'nap pile',1,24870,'For the sleeping beauties and the wandering insomniacs who enjoy a good night sleep.')
 ;
UPDATE `DiscordUser` SET ClubId = 6 WHERE Id=1;
UPDATE `DiscordUser` SET ClubId = 3 WHERE Id=7;
UPDATE `DiscordUser` SET ClubId = 4 WHERE Id=14;
UPDATE `DiscordUser` SET ClubId = 5 WHERE Id=32;
UPDATE `DiscordUser` SET ClubId = 2 WHERE Id=91;

-- LOAD Remaining DiscordUser rows (note incomplete)
INSERT INTO `DiscordUser` (Id,AvatarId,Discriminator,UserId,DateAdded,Username,ClubId,LastLevelUp,NotifyOnLevelUp,LastXpGain,TotalXp,IsClubAdmin,CurrencyAmount) VALUES 
 --(1,'6d5212a0f5e862d57c8ffc6f254a2e85','1458',299779864045682689,'2017-10-07 18:02:04.8287878','Anubis',6,'2018-03-27 02:22:26.362966',0,'2017-11-17 01:19:14.0313957',7056,1,280),
 --(2,'3b37e0f635706f81fdde2b6de9889283','9810',181200115539640321,'2017-10-07 18:04:39.767728','AnnaHime',NULL,'2018-01-02 02:27:38.8011863',0,'2017-11-16 01:29:49.0371488',429,0,360),
 (3,'a3cd92d397ad357834d0e6c9f10bfc59','0429',145356302347010048,'2017-10-07 18:04:49.786657','Rebel Lucy',NULL,'2018-03-26 12:55:21.1149964',0,'2017-11-17 22:21:24.0263741',6876,0,3600),
 (4,'7225dccaab1c93896657a61e18595378','5286',84689434536050688,'2017-10-07 18:05:44.765554','scarletflame234',NULL,'2018-03-28 22:56:28.7427437',0,'2017-11-17 23:21:41.4446535',13368,0,288),
 (5,'c1316bc0673f4a2709b3ce550ed54395','0760',303279191116480514,'2017-10-07 18:06:39.7664015','zachary',NULL,'2018-03-02 03:48:43.4817755',0,'2017-11-17 18:44:14.1082867',210,0,50),
 (6,'2ed95eae7c3088c46b23e71578dacc42','8801',161369834314137601,'2017-10-07 18:07:04.7672808','Kou',NULL,'2018-03-07 06:24:32.3405246',0,'2017-11-17 23:20:00.0648699',2640,0,55),
 --(7,'612c67b6eb57d8806dcc92ed45b3a6d0','0396',177502331582021639,'2017-10-07 18:11:09.7830603','Tsuchimursu',3,'2018-03-28 17:45:53.7399883',0,'2017-11-17 15:53:59.084885',18156,1,4725),
 (8,'5b1d239935ab4dd6d3eee98954601d52','9859',179093512610906113,'2017-10-07 18:13:54.7939334','TheCorty',NULL,'2017-11-12 12:07:36.4752178',0,'2017-11-12 23:47:26.4744132',2460,0,205), ...........
```

- **NOTE** The SQL from **-- LOAD Remaining DiscordUser rows**, will not work as it's only intended to show how ID's 1,2 and 7 have been commented out, as should be rows 14, 32 and 91 as they have already been loaded, the other close to 600 rows should be included.

Note I've just also loaded the outstanding 3 waifu tables so all data can be retrieved (assuming that none has been lost due to the corruption). `PRAGMA integrity_check;` returns OK.

Comment: Ok I'll try that! Thank you for this long and full answer!

Comment: Looking at it now again. Redoing the the above up to but not including Clubs/DiscordUser and successors (just finished). Going to save at that stage. Then copy db and try first creating empty tables and then do inserts after to see it that will work. (i.e circular references, as I call them may be ok, just you might have to have tables created before inserts).